# How can I run a callback after a loop of Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Specifically, given a list of data, I want to loop over that list and do a fetch for each element of that data before I combine it all afterward. The thing is, as written, the code iterates through the entire list immediately, starting all the operations at once. Then, even though the fetch operations are still running, the then call I have after all that runs, before the data could've been processed.

I read something about putting all the `Promises` in an array, then passing that array to a Promise.all() call, followed by a then that will have access to all that processed data as intended, but I'm not sure how exactly to go about doing it in this case, since I have nested `Promises` in this for loop.

```
        for(var i in repoData) {
            var repoName = repoData[i].name;
            var repoUrl = repoData[i].url;
            (function(name, url) {
                Promise.all([fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${username}/${repoData[i].name}/commits`),
                    fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${username}/${repoData[i].name}/pulls`)])
                .then(function(results) {   
                    Promise.all([results[0].json(), results[1].json()])
                    .then(function(json) {
                        //console.log(json[0]);
                        var commits = json[0];
                        var pulls = json[1];
                        var repo = {};
                        repo.name = name;
                        repo.url = url;
                        repo.commitCount =  commits.length;
                        repo.pullRequestCount = pulls.length;
                        console.log(repo);
                        user.repositories.push(repo);
                    }); 
                });
            })(repoName, repoUrl);
        }
    }).then(function() {
        var payload = new Object();
        payload.user = user;
        //console.log(payload);
        //console.log(repoData[0]);
        res.send(payload);
    });
```

Comment: This is not how you should be using Promises...

Comment: Is the code at Question complete? What is the last `.then()` chained to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally when you need to run asynchronous operations for all of the items in an array, the answer is to use `Promise.all(arr.map(...))` and this case appears to be no exception.

Also remember that you need to `return` values in your `then` callbacks in order to pass values on to the next `then` (or to the `Promise.all` aggregating everything).

When faced with a complex situation, it helps to break it down into smaller pieces. In this case, you can isolate the code to query data for a single repo into its own function. Once you've done that, the code to query data for *all* of them boils down to:

```
Promise.all(repoData.map(function (repoItem) {
  return getDataForRepo(username, repoItem);
}))
```

Please try the following:

```
// function to query details for a single repo
function getDataForRepo(username, repoInfo) {
  return Promise
    .all([
      fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${username}/${repoInfo.name}/commits`),
      fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${username}/${repoInfo.name}/pulls`)
    ])
    .then(function (results) {
      return Promise.all([results[0].json(), results[1].json()])
    })
    .then(function (json) {
      var commits = json[0];
      var pulls = json[1];

      var repo = {
        name: repoInfo.name,
        url: repoInfo.url,
        commitCount: commits.length,
        pullRequestCount: pulls.length
      };

      console.log(repo);
      return repo;
    });
}

Promise.all(repoData.map(function (repoItem) {
  return getDataForRepo(username, repoItem);
})).then(function (retrievedRepoData) {
  console.log(retrievedRepoData);

  var payload = new Object();
  payload.user = user;
  //console.log(payload);
  //console.log(repoData[0]);
  res.send(payload);
});
```